# TypeScript narrowing type parameter based on union type at the callsite

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, union-types

## Identified Solution

I realized that I just needed to utilize [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#constraints) like so

```js
function nameAnimal<Type extends { name: string }>(animal: Type, name: string): Type { 
  animal.name = name 
  return animal
}
```

While this may be insufficient if one truly wanted it to be limited to just `Animal` types, it's certainly more than sufficient for the use case.

## Problem

I'm trying to essentially be able to say "whatever type in the union type A you call this function with, it will return that same concrete type".

So for example, with the following context:

```
type Animal = Dog | Cat

type Dog = {
  name: string
  ...
}

type Cat = {
  name: string
  ...
}

function nameAnimal(animal: Animal, name: string): Animal {
  animal.name = name
  return animal
}

function handleDog(dog: Dog) {
  // dog specific code
}
```

With the above context, if `fido` is of type `Dog`, then the following fails

```
handleDog(nameAnimal(fido, 'Fido'))
```

Because `nameAnimal` returns `Animal` instead of `Dog`.

Is there a way to have `nameAnimal` specify that it returns the same concrete type it receives? A loosely similar concept in Java can be accomplished with generics as follows

```
public static <T extends Animal> T nameAnimal(T animal, String name) {
  animal.name = name
  return animal
}
```

Again, I understand this is very different, as it involves class hierarchies and inheritance. I can imagine that this is an innate limitation on union types in general.

Comment: Answers belong in an answer post, not as part of the question itself.  Please [edit] to remove the  answer and move it to its own answer post below.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use generic parameter:

```js
type Animal = Dog | Cat

type Dog = {
  name: string
  tag: 'Dog'
}

type Cat = {
  name: string
  tag: 'Cat'
}

function nameAnimal<A extends Animal>(animal: A, name: string): A {
  animal.name = name
  return animal
}

const fido: Dog = {
  name: 'Tom',
  tag: 'Dog'
}

function handleDog(dog: Dog) {
  // dog specific code
}

handleDog(nameAnimal(fido, 'Fido')) // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKyOGN)